# how to change the request method of the function load of jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

well, I use the function load of jquery to update the some elements of the current page,
but before that, I first to use the method ajax to submit a request to server with request method 'DELETE', 
when the client retrieve the response, if the request successful, the client should to use the   method load of jquery to update the current page,

but when to use the load to request, the default request method is DELETE, not GET or POST, i thought may be the some cache affected the request method.

so, how to change the request method of the function load, or other solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you post the code you've used for each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax()` does not affect `.load()`. The only reason that `.load()` uses `DELETE` is that the defaults have been changed, e.g. with `$.ajaxSetup()` or some filter / event handler.

Comment: you are right, i use this `$.ajaxSetup({type:'get'});` it's ok, thanks.